# How the dataframe picks the schema of the parquet with merge schema turned off? How its determining which folders schema it should pick from?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, apache-spark-sql

I have two different folders of parquet file, with both having two different schema format. With the merge schema turned off it picks the schema of one folder and sticks to it. Would like to know whats the logic behind it to pick that folder's schema instead of the other.

Comment: Exact logic is pretty well described in the comments https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4308/files (in particular see [this](https://github.com/liancheng/spark/blob/b6946e67c0bbf30534aa6ebfd6b5926400529a09/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/dataTypes.scala#L947) and [this](https://github.com/liancheng/spark/blob/b6946e67c0bbf30534aa6ebfd6b5926400529a09/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/parquet/newParquet.scala#L242))